# Active Directory Virtual User

Tags: .net, windows, iis, active-directory

Does there exist any concept which says that there exists a concept of virtual user in AD?

Comment: what do you means by virtual user? what is the different between actual user/temp user with virtual user?

Comment: As i said someone told me this but I didn't believe it. According to what you said i would assume there are only actual and temp user but concept of a virtual user doesn't exist. If I'm following you right then can you explain me what is the difference between an actual and temp user?

Comment: The person might refer to FTP user by 'virtual user' because FTP can use either AD user, which is actual user in some sense, or they can use a logical user owned by FTP, which is virtual user in some sense. Sorry about temp user and actual user, you can say they are the same, their is only one kind of user in AD.